# Arithmetic with very small numbers in R

Tags: r, floating-point

I'm trying to work with some probabilities that get very small which causes issues. For example

```
probs <- c(4.225867e-03,3.463125e-04,2.480971e-05,1.660538e-06,1.074064e-07,6.829168e-09,4.305051e-10,2.702241e-11,1.692533e-12,1.058970e-13,6.622117e-15,4.139935e-16,2.587807e-17,1.617488e-18,1.010964e-19,6.318630e-21,3.949177e-22 2.468246e-23,1.542657e-24,9.641616e-26,6.026013e-27,3.766259e-28,2.353912e-29,1.471195e-30,9.194971e-32
```

However any arithmetic with this vector causes everything after the 12th entry to round off to zero (probably because it's less than .Machine$double.eps). For example:

```
probs > 0
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

but

```
1-probs < 1
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I've tried using the gmp package but I'm doing combinatoric based calculations and as.bigq(probs) gets really slow when raised to large powers.

Any ways to get around this?

Comment: To get around these kinds of problems it's common to work with log probabilities, so that you can sum the probabilities rather than multiplying (which is often the cause of tiny probabilities).

Comment: @Marius Somewhat surprisingly, this doesn't seem to be a duplicate (maybe I didn't search correctly). It would be nice to have a canonical answer about the use of log probabilities in R to improve numerical accuracy. Perhaps you could expand on your comment and make it an answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman Do we really need the log-probability strategy to be stated separately for every language? I know I've seen similar questions in other languages.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Fair question. Not every language but R is a special case since it is the standard language for statistical computing. Many people who use R have a decent undergraduate background in probability and statistics but never studied statistical computing per se or graduate-level stats where the topic might be introduced. Also, even though there are numerous books on R, surprisingly few of them discuss the utility of the `log.p` optional parameter which is included in many R functions. Thus, I think it would be useful to have such an answer in the R tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The case of very small probabilities comes up often in machine learning and other statistical computing topics.  You are getting a precision error because of the limitations of the internal representation of floating point numbers.  This can be solved using arbitrary precision arithmetic, but that is not commonly done.

The most popular solution is to use a l[og transformation to represent your probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_probability) and then use addition instead of multiplication. This is referred to as *log-likelihood*.  This transformation avoids the problem of very small numbers, and in addition, the log-likelihood values can be used directly to compare the probability of things (lower log-likelihood always means lower probability).

Note that there is a [subtle distinction between likelihood and probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/what-is-the-difference-between-likelihood-and-probability), but the log transformation turning very small numbers in to negative ones with less variety in the number of decimal places works regardless.